# Insert 10M rows Postgresql temp table and select all rows is too slow

Tags: postgresql, function, insert, temp

I have eleven tables in PostgreSQL 9.4 and I create a function that selects all from tables. I create it with temp table that is inserted all eleven tables, the finish of inserting then select all from the temp table. But this function executes 43 seconds, it is so slow. I increase temp-buffer to 100 MB and 1000 MB from 8 MB. But the execution is not decreasing. How can I optimize query and increase performance?

I create indexes on the temp table, but it does not increase performance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_useractivitylog_ndis()
  RETURNS TABLE(loguser_name text, logaction_name character varying, logaction_type character varying, logdetail_1 text, logdetail_2 text, logtime1 timestamp without time zone, logtime2 timestamp without time zone, logaction_time timestamp without time zone)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $function$
      begin
          create temp table
          temp_table
          (
            tempuser_name text,
            tempaction_name varchar(100),
            tempaction_type varchar(500),
            tempdetail1 text,
            tempdetail2 text,
            temptime1 timestamp without time zone,
            temptime2 timestamp without time zone,
            tempaction_time timestamp without time zone
          ) on
          commit drop ;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tblone;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tbltwo;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tblthree;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tblfour;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tblfive;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tblsix;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tblseven;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tbleigth;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tblnine;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tblten;

          insert into temp_table (tempuser_name, tempaction_name, tempaction_type, tempdetail1, tempdetail2, temptime1, temptime2, tempaction_time)
              select * from public.tbleleven;

        return query
            select 
                tempuser_name ,
                tempaction_name ,
                tempaction_type,
                tempdetail1 ,
                tempdetail2 ,
                temptime1 ,
                temptime2 ,
                tempaction_time 
            from temp_table
            order by tempaction_time desc, tempuser_name, tempaction_name;
      end $function$ ;
```

```
Function Scan on fn_useractivitylog_ndis  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=184) (actual time=39827.375..40817.591 rows=10200021 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.019 ms 
Execution time: 41076.709 ms
```

Comment: Why do you have 11 tables with an identical structure to begin with? That sounds like a really bad database design. Why isn't that a single table?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a temp table, why not just use a union in the return query:

```
RETURN QUERY
  SELECT tempuser_name, tempaction_name,tempaction_type, 
         tempdetail1,tempdetail2,temptime1,temptime2, tempaction_time
  FROM public.tblone
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tempuser_name, tempaction_name,tempaction_type, 
         tempdetail1,tempdetail2,temptime1,temptime2, tempaction_time
  FROM public.tbltwo
  ...
  ORDER BY tempaction_time desc, tempuser_name, tempaction_name;
```

Comment: And then change the function to `language sql` or even better: create a view out of the UNION statement

Comment: I do not change the function to language SQL because of some sql command is only work pgsql. @a_horse_with_no_name. And also creating view gets duplicate rows, unfortunately.

Comment: I used a union but the execution time was 39 seconds. @SeanJohnston

Comment: @MustafaBYKSY: your function shows no PL/pgSQL language constructs.

Comment: @MustafaBYKSY: if that UNION ALL shows duplicates, your temp table would have duplicates as well

Comment: My next step would be to do an EXPLAIN ANALYSE on the union query. I'd guess that the sorting is going to be the big time sink. How many rows are returned in total? Have a look at increasing the 'work_mem' parameter to get it to sort in memory rather than disk.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right that this function shows no PL/pgSQL language constructs. But this is a basic function, I may enhance this function in later times with adding some SQL commands that only work PL/pgSQL.

Comment: @SeanJohnston 10M rows are returned. work_mem is 100 MB. Also, I optimize the effective_cache_size and shared_buffers.  Can I increase temp_buffer at the start of the function and decrease its end of the function? Is it possible or effective?

Comment: @MustafaBYKSY The temp_buffers setting only affects access of temporary tables. You need to look at the work_mem settings controls how much memory to use for things like sorting (ORDER BY) before using temporary disk files for sorting. So if you stick with the temporary table approach then temp_buffers will help with the initial population of the temporary table, but you still need to look at work_mem. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/runtime-config-resource.html)

Comment: @SeanJohnston, I do the following steps;
 1. In the function that select tables with union statement, I set work_mem: set session work_mem='2097151', and then the result is 8183 ms.
2. In the function that select tables with the temp table, I set work_mem: set session work_mem='2097151'  and set temp_buffers: set local temp_buffers:'300MB'. The result is 14596 ms.